# Determining the header of each column in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I created a JTable that has 6 rows and 8 columns. I want to set the header for each column. I tried the code bellow and it didn't work for me.

```
    JTable apartma = new JTable(6,8);

    apartma.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setHeaderValue("newHeader");
```

[image: Header not showing up]

Comment: do you want to set a header to only one column ?

Comment: No. This was just a test. I want to set a header for each column (8).

Comment: You might like to take a look at [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a complete code, but it seems that the problem is the table header is not visible.

In order to show the JTable's header, you should put the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`, and do not add your `JTable` instance directly to the underlying container:

```
JScrollPane sc = new JScrollPane(apartma);
yourPanel.add(sc);
```

Also you may want to pass a `String[]` or `Vector<String>` as the titles for all of the `JTable` columns header, to the `TableModel`.

Hope this would be helpful.